can I send "sudo su" command automatically , when I do ssh to a host?
suppose that I do ssh to a host:
test$ ssh host1
test@host1$ 

I need to do the "sudo su" manually and then enter password.
test$ ssh host1
test@host1$ sudo su
Password: **********
root@host1:/home/test# 

is there any configuration which can be added to the .ssh/config or somewhere else that it does this step for me?
P.S.: I use a linux terminal for doing the ssh!!
ssh test@host1  "su -c \"sudo su\""

sudo su is already “bad” enough (use sudo -i or sudo -s instead), but what’s that final command line supposed to be?

Are you asking how to SSH into a session as a specific user?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Perhaps putting if [ "$PS1" ]; then exec sudo -i; fi in your .bashrc? Definitely have an open window while you're making this change so you can undo it if necessary.

My inner InfoSec guy wants to say that creating an automatic, no-user-interaction way to remotely get root on a system is probably always a bad idea.

@Spiff Not always a no-go. In order to push out commands to 700+ Linux systems, we have one server that is allowed to ssh to root on the remote systems. That one system is locked down tight. Limited accounts, iptable rules, etc. Without safeguards in place however, I would agree with you.

echo 'sudo su' >> ~/.bashrc on host1?

You can run the sudo directly from ssh. The -t flag assigns a terminal so that sudo will treat the session as an interactive one and prompt for a password. (If -t fails you then use -tt.)
ssh -t host1 sudo -s

There is absolutely never any need to run a construct such as sudo su despite what certain distributions' documentation suggest. The sudo command prompts for your password and grants you root privileges. The su command when run with no arguments grants you root privileges subject to having the root password - but if you're root then the password prompt is skipped.
The result is a bit like this hypothetical conversation

Hello sudo, please can I have root privileges?
Password please… thanks… here you are
That's great, now please run su (as root) to give me root privileges
Oh ok, you were already root but here you go.

